# Using CURL and JSON to parse variables from server A to server B

Tags: php, mysql, json, variables, curl

I'm trying to run mysql queries from a remote server (server B) and then return the info from the DB back as variables to the original server (server A) using CURL and JSON.

This is what the end result will be:

1. When somebody visits a page from server A, a request will then be sent out from server A to server B which will then connect to a db.
2. Once server B has connected to the db, it will take information from certain rows and fields and then send it back to server A as variables such as `$name` `$email` etc etc.
3. Once server A has received the info, it will then echo out and etc etc...

Here is the code I've got so far...

**Server A**

```
<?

include ('../reference.php');


$post_fields = array(
    'unq__id' => $_reference,
    'gdi__username' => $sponsor_GDI_id,
);
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/WP/d__access.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);



?>
```

**Server B**

```
<?

include ('config/wp__2135432135435135412312534.php');

mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$reference = $_POST['__id'];
$variable_name = $_POST['__username'];
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE ". "username = '$variable_name' AND Unique_id = '$reference'");


?>
```

I haven't actually tested the above code yet because I'm trying to find a way to send all those variables from Server B to Server A (`_email, $s, $tst etc etc`)

So I'm not even sure if what I've got so far will even work....

Now from a previous question, I was told I could use JSON to send variables back to Server A... "Perhaps you could have server B return a JSON encoded string, which you could decode on Server A."

Could anyone tell me how I would go about doing something like that? Or any simpler alternatives would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your B server, you could construct a single array, that will contain all the data you need to send back to A :

```
$result = array(
    'sponsor_first_nme' => $sponsor_first_nme, 
    'sponsor_second_nme' => $sponsor_second_nme, 
);
```

Then, you can [**`json_encode()`**](http://www.php.net/json_encode) that array and echo it :

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

This means you script on B will echo some valid JSON.

Then, on A, just get this result as a string, like you already do :

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

And [**`json_decode()`**](http://www.php.net/json_decode) that string, to get back some PHP data you can use *(either array or object, depending on the parameters you used)* :

```
$data = json_decode($result);
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. I've added all the code above but i was wondering, can i now just use the variables being sent from server B to server A as if it was an included file or do i have to do something else before i can use the parsed variables ($sponsor_second_nme, $sponsor_first_nme)?

Comment: With this idea, your variables are now part of `$data`, which is either an array or an object -- which means you'll have to use `$data['sponsor_first_nme']` or `$data->sponsor_first_nme`.

Comment: hey, i just tried the following: "$sponsor_first_nme = $data->sponsor_first_nme;" and "$sponsor_first_nme = $sponsor_first_nme = $data->sponsor_first_nme;". I then echoed out $sposnor_first_nme. The first one returns completely blank but with no errors and the second one returns an error "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /sponsor-script.php on line 19" Line 19 is where the defining the variable is ($sponsor_first_nme = $data->sponsor_first_nme;). Really appreciate your help.

Comment: As you have not passed true as a second parameter to `json_decode()`, you must use object-access : `$data->name_of_the_property` *(and using array-access results in a fatal error, as you've seen)*. If something's empty, that's odd -- did you try using `var_dump()` or both `$result` and `$data` ?

Comment: hey, I've figured out the problem. It seems that server A is not sending the variables to server B which is causing problems selecting a certain row in the DB. But the code you provided is working fine as i tested it without using any variables. So the issue lies in either "$post_fields = array(
    'unq__id' => $sponsor_reference,
    'gdi__username' => $sponsor_GDI_id,
);" or "$reference = $_POST['unq__id'];
$variable_name = $_POST['gdi__username'];
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE ". "GDI_Username = '$variable_name' AND Unique_id = '$reference'");"